# How can i do the same cURL POST request with PHP

Tags: php, curl, bottle

I need to execute the same code from php. As you can see, in this code i include json as context.
This code is now executed from a linux terminal:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"leer_datos", "params": {"bd":"escuela","tabla":"secretaria","id":"2"}}' http://localhost:8090/rpc/alchemy
```

I saw other questions and responses on stackoverflow, such as

```
$url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

but i could not fix it.

The idea is pass the data to a file with bottle framework ready to receive this data. This file is written and tested with the cURL call in terminal.

Comment: Have you considered using PHP's cURL functions? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Have you tried `http_build_query(json_encode($data))` ?

Comment: @Javad, i tried with $data = "{'jsonrpc': '2.0','method':'entidades','params':'entidades.json'}" 
'content' => http_build_query(json_encode($data))
with bottle running in rpc.py. I open the php file with this code with the browser but nothing happens.
Jay Blanchard, i considered cURL but i don't understood nothing.